# Split Refactoring and Move to Outer Scope Refactoring in one action

Tags: c#, resharper

I often hit this pattern while coding...

```
void somefunc(bool awesome)
{
   if(awesome) {
      var blah = SomethingThatResultsInBlah(); 
   }
}
```

I'd of just typed var blah... and now realize I need access outside the if and ideally I want "Move Declaration To Outer Scope"

Resharper doesn't have this ( that I'm aware of! ) but it does have split, and it does have move to outer scope.   So I'll end up doing split

```
void somefunc(bool awesome)
{
   if(awesome) {
      Blah blah;
      blah = Blah(); 
   }
}
```

followed by move to outer scope

```
   void somefunc(bool awesome)
    {
       Blah blah;
       if(awesome) {
          blah = Blah(); 
       }
    }
```

is there a way in R# to make a single action to do it one shot

Comment: I don't know of a way, but I've wanted to do that myself.  A related scenario that I encounter is an if/else block that has local variables in each branch with the same name, and I'd like to pop the declaration of all of those to being outside of the branch and leave the initialization within each branch.  Please let me know if you learn of a way to do either of those!